# Hide text in category pages for not logged in customer in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I need to hide a button that leads to a price list in my category pages.

I create my pages by creating static block and link that with code:

`{{block type="core/template" template="catalog/category/SacToiledeJute.phtml"}}`

I need now to hide a text that include the button in the SacToiledeJute.phtml page  for not logged in customer but not the whole page.

I have searched in google on the code to hide that button with no luck.

I hope I can find this here.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very simple..

Just add this code in SacToiledeJute.phtml:

```
$isLoggedIn = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn();

if($isLoggedIn){
        // your code
        // here
}
```

Please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks Mohti for your reply, my internet stopped after posting this question I just got it back. I added the code like that: `<td colspan="2">

<?php
$isLoggedIn = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn();
if($isLoggedIn){
<p class="spts-button"><a href="http://www.cabas-durables.fr/telechargements/Tarif%20Sacs%20Toile%20de%20Jute%20Personnalises%202014.pdf" target="_blank">Télécharger le tarif sacs toile de jute standard</a></p>
}
?>

</td>` But I got error on the page: Parse error:

Comment: Here is the page: http://www.cabas-durables.fr/magento/index.php/sacs-reutilisables/sac-toile-de-jute.html

Comment: I got error on the page: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/cabasdfr/public_html/magento/app/design/frontend/default/custom_theme/template/catalog/category/SacToiledeJute.phtml on line 488

Comment: It works, Thank you very much, I did it like that: `<?php $isLoggedIn = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn();
if($isLoggedIn){echo('Prendre connaissance du tarif des sacs standard ?');}
else {echo('Pas encore enregistré ?');} ?>`